# Async in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asynchronous

I have this webservice which is sucking in data about exchange rates, my problem with it is it takes alot of time to load. So i want to get the data loaded async but when i call the GetRatesASync() method it says

> "Asynchronous operations are not allowed in this context. Page starting an asynchronous operation has to have the Async attribute set to true and an asynchronous operation can only be started on a page prior to PreRenderComplete event."

Oh by the way im using a soap service and an MVC UserControl if that helps at all and i placed the GetRatesASync() method in protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e).
So how do I got about getting this bloody data ASync with jquery after the page is loaded. 
And is there a way to make this getting data thing faster

Comment: May I as why you're using SOAP? If you're already using JQuery to get the results, why not just use an ActionResult that sends back for example a JSON object, or the MVC UserControl you're using? There is great support built into the MVC framework for working with partial postbacks...

Comment: I don't think getting the data asynchronously is going to help you here (OnPreRender is a server-side event anyway). Can you cache the exchange rates?

Comment: @James Avery can't cahce the hosting doesn't allow @Thomas I'm looking in to that aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery, how about: 1) wait for the page to load in the browser; 2) call a javascript function that makes an asynchronous call to the server; 3) wait for the result; 4) when the result arrives from the server, display it in the browser?

Something like:

Javascript/jquery in web page:

```
$().ready(GetExchangeRates);
function GetExchangeRates()
{
    // TODO: Maybe show a *loading* animation.
    $.get("/Currency/GetExchangeRates",
        null, GetExchangeRatesCompleted, "json");
}
function GetExchangeRatesCompleted(result)
{
    // TODO: Hide *loading* animation.
    // TODO: Display result on page.
}
```

Controller action (C#):

```
public class CurrencyController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult GetExchangeRates()
    {
        var exchangeRates = _slowWebService.GetExchangeRates();
        return Json(exchangeRates);
    }
}
```

---

Another thing:

If you can't cache the exchange rates, how about saving them in an xml file in the App_Data folder, with an entry that says when the exchange rates were last retrieved from the slow webservice, and then refreshing that xml file when it's older than some specified time interval?

Answer (score 2):

If you want async in MVC you could use the [AsyncController included in ASP.NET MVC Futures](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/08/Using-the-ASPNET-MVC-Futures-AsyncController.aspx).

But async operation won't make your webservice any faster... it will only prevent it from blocking your thread.

Comment: async operation will be faster than sync operations. Sync operations always create a little bit of overhead. Check also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx

Comment: @Silvermind : it *can* give you more requests per second, which is **not** the same thing as being *faster*. It's async that has overhead (for example it breaks locality).

Comment: I stand corrected. But in addition I like the events in async webservices better it gives me cleaner code with FaultExceptions being in the EventArgs. However I misread overhead in async.

Answer (score 0):

***here is a simpler code without AsyncController but using TPL Task***

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index() 
    {
      var exchangeRates = await _slowWebService.GetExchangeRates(); // this method should return Task<IEnumerable<ExchangeRate>>
        return Json(exchangeRates);

    return View(result);
    }
```

check this video [mvc4 and tpl task action methods](http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/08/06/video-taking-advantage-of-tpl-in-mvc4/#comment-6467)